# Wordpress site - create download link for .exe

Tags: wordpress

I am new with Wordpress.  I need to get a button or link to a .exe file on my Wordpress site.  I have put code in the text portion of this site, as required by the file type.  But no matter what code I use I always get "404 Page Not Found".  I have tried, in addition to the .exe file, a .txt file and a .jpg file all of which have been uploaded to the site.  I have cleared the browser cache.  I have tried it in Chrome and IE.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdNV1.jpg).

Some of the code I have tried:

```
<a href="/downloads/textdoc.txt"> Click Here</a>

<a href="http://cronapacific.com/downloads/textdoc.txt"> Click Here</a>
```

but always resulting in "404 Page Not Found".  There is a file called "textdoc.txt" in a folder called "downloads" in the root directory of the site.  It has read permission.  Please suggest a method to determine the problem.

---

**.htaccess File**

```
# BEGIN 
# exclude directories /download/ and /downloads/ from rewrites RewriteEngine 
On RewriteRule ^(downloads|download)($|/) - [L] 
# END exclude directories /download/ and /downloads/ from rewrites 

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/downloads/"    

RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Check your upload location. Where did you upload it? within `wp-content/uploads/` directory?

Comment: No.  I created a directory called "downloads" in the root directory and put the file there.  At least I think I did.  Is it possible to attached an image of my file manager here?

Comment: Yes, update your question with the image. Are you able to access the .exe file directly on the server?

Comment: It might be a htaccess issue as well. You should post the code in your .htaccess file with your question too.

Comment: Bear with me please.  How do I upload an image here?  (I have Snagit if that helps.)  as for your other question ...

Comment: Click 'edit' on your main question, you will see an image upload icon.

Comment: I think I can Access the file on the server because if I right click on it I can select "Copy" and then a popup appears asking me where I want to copy it to.

Comment: Sharing the image and .htaccess file would be useful. Your .htaccess file is located in root directory with wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes.

Comment: I have added the image.  This is the htaccess:

Comment: You need to move `downloads` directory into `public_html` directory. The current setup won't allow you to access downloads.

Comment: # BEGIN exclude directories /download/ and /downloads/ from rewrites
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(downloads|download)($|/) - [L]
# END exclude directories /download/ and /downloads/ from rewrites
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I don't know how to format this.  If I hit the enter key it shuts down the comment.

Comment: Delete your htaccess comment, I moved it to the main post.

Comment: Do as I mentioned above, move `downloads` directory into `public_html` directory. The current setup won't allow you to access downloads.

Comment: Can you see the image?  this is the code for the .exe                               <a href="/public_html/SELMS-setup.ext"> Click Here</a>

Comment: Okay I'll do that.

Comment: Try this instead: `<a href="http://cronapacific.com/SELMS-setup.exe">`. Keep in mind, you don't need to add `public_html` in your links.

Comment: Okay there is now a folder in public_html called downloads with a copy of SELMS-setup.exe in it

Comment: Try either of these: `<a href="http://cronapacific.com/SELMS-setup.exe">` or `<a href="http://cronapacific.com/downloads/SELMS-setup.exe">`. Let me know.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work:     <a href="http://cronapacific.com/downloads/SELMS-setup.exe">Click here</a>

Comment: k, I updated your post again. Can you remove the first four lines from your `.htaccess` file? Check above. Make your `.htaccess` file starts with `# BEGIN WordPress`, remove everything above it.

Comment: ok will do give me a minute

Comment: no joy.  same result.

Comment: Hang on. Let me check something.

Comment: Go ahead and check your main post again, added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/downloads/"` to your `htaccess` file. Can you check if it works?

Comment: Check the main post in this thread?  Yes I will add that line to htaccess

Comment: same result unfortunately

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/downloads/"
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress